# Accessing a nested polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

Let's say I've defined two custom Polymer elements

```
<!-- Define inner elements -->
<polymer-element name="child-el" attributes="foo">
    <script>
        Polymer('child-el', {
            /* -- Attributes ------------------------------------------------ */
            foo: 'qux'

            /* -- Lifecycle ------------------------------------------------- */
            created: function() {
                console.log('Creating a Child');
            },
            /* -- Public Methods -------------------------------------------- */
            getFoo: function() {
                return [this.foo];
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<!-- Define custom element -->
<polymer-element name="parent-el">
    <script>
        Polymer('parent-el', {
            /* -- Lifecycle ------------------------------------------------- */
            created: function() {
                console.log('Creating a Container');
            },
            ready: function() {
                // This is the part that doesn't seem to work
                console.log(this.children[0].getFoo());
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

And then in the markup which uses these elements:

```
<container>
    <child foo="bar"></child>
    <child foo="baz"></child>
</container>
```

As I've commented in the code I'd like to use the methods and/or attributes of the custom element child nodes of the custom element (**not** the child nodes of a template). Naturally, I'm aware there will be more than simply looping through an array, but at this point I'm not entirely sure how to essentially access each of the custom children as their Polymer types.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an answer and brief discussion with [@ebidel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274673/ebidel) I came up with the full solution to my problem. Basically, I wanted to access child Polymer elements of a parent Polymer element within the parent's code, but ultimately I ended up doing it the other way around.

The lesson is that by the time `domReady` is called, the elements have been upgraded to include the methods which you've defined. Bueno.

```
<!-- Define inner elements -->
<polymer-element name="child-el" attributes="foo">
    <script>
        Polymer('child-el', {
            /* -- Attributes ------------------------------------------------ */
            foo: 'qux'

            /* -- Lifecycle ------------------------------------------------- */
            created: function() {
                console.log('Creating a Child');
            },
            ready: function () {
                // Not ready to access this.parentNode at this point
            },
            domReady: function () {
                this.async(function () {
                    // By this point this.parentNode is upgraded according to
                    // http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#zerochildren
                    this.parentNode.doFooWithChild(this);
                });
            /* -- Public Methods -------------------------------------------- */
            getFoo: function() {
                return [this.foo];
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>

<!-- Define custom element -->
<polymer-element name="parent-el">
    <script>
        Polymer('parent-el', {
            /* -- Lifecycle ------------------------------------------------- */
            created: function() {
                console.log('Creating a Container');
            },
            ready: function() {
                // Not ready to access this.children at this point
            },
            doFooWithChild: function(child) {
                console.log(child.getFoo());
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

The safest time to access an element's light DOM children is in the `domReady()` callback. `created`/`ready`/`attached` nay be too early because the element is not yet guaranteed to be in the DOM and children upgraded.

- http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#zerochildren
- http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods

Note: "container" and "child" are not valid custom element names. You need a "-" somewhere in the name. So "container-element" or "child-el" would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ebidel. It hasn't actually answered my question but you have helped me with a potential "gotcha" there :)

What was actually trying to do was create some kind of communication between the child and parent through methods I have defined, but luckily the first link you sent me to, at http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#parentnode has helped me figure out that it can be done in this.async's callback. I'll edit my question to be clearer and then write an answer which details all this soon. Thanks!

Comment: You should actually wait until domReady, not attached. Attached is too early in some cases.  Updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, haha! I mean, in my case it's actually been working just fine in attached but I'll change it, just in case.

Comment: Attached will work for certain cases but fail in others. As a general rule if thumb, domReady is a safer bet.

Comment: Cool, that's what I'll use from now on. Thanks! Like I said, with you answer I worked out how to do what I eventually wanted to do so I made an answer for that :)